# Changing the window size of Signal using AppleScript (error 10006)

Tags: applescript, signals

I would like to change the size Signal' window:

```
tell application "Signal" set bounds of front window to {0, 23, 1280, 791} end tell
```

but I have error:

```
error "Signal — błąd: Nie można ustawić bounds of window 1 na {0, 23, 1280, 791}" number -10006 from bounds of window 1
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **Signal for Mac** from https://signal.org/download/, then **Signal.app** does not contain an **AppleScript** *dictionary*, e.g. **Signal.sdef**, *file* and also when trying to add it to the **Library** in **Script Editor** it errors with:

> **Add Item.**
>
> Unable to add the item because it is not scriptable.

This means, sans some basic *commands*, is not *directly scriptable* and you'll need to use **System Events** and or **UI Scripting** to manipulate it using **AppleScript**.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

```
tell application "System Events" 
    tell application process "Signal"
        tell front window
            set {position, size} to {{0, 23}, {1280, 791}}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [delay](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) command may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: almost perfect, but it doesn't change the width of window :(